# Send Simultaneous HTTP request using guzzle library

Tags: php, asynchronous, guzzle, synchronous

I want to send simultaneous request and get data. here is my current code:

```
 public function getDispenceryforAllPage($dispencery)
    {
        $data = array();
        $promiseGetPagination = $this->client->getAsync($dispencery)
            ->then(function ($response) {
                return $this->getPaginationNumber($response->getBody()->getContents());           
                });
               $Pagination = $promiseGetPagination->wait();


                for ($i=1; $i<=$Pagination; $i++) {

                        $GetAllproducts = $this->client->getAsync($dispencery.'?page='.$i)
                        ->then(function ($response) {

                            $promise =  $this->getData($response->getBody()->getContents()); 
                            return $promise;       
                            });
                            $data[] = $GetAllproducts->wait();  

        }
        return $data; 

    }
```

I want to get all paginated data of a specific page. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a bunch of promises concurrently, you need of the functions: [all()](https://github.com/guzzle/promises/blob/v1.3.1/src/functions.php#L219), some(), each() and other from guzzlehttp/promises package.

Try this one:

```
public function getDispenceryforAllPage($dispencery)
{
    $Pagination = $this->getPaginationNumber(
        $this->client->get($dispencery)->getBody()->getContents()
    );

    $GetAllProductPromises = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $Pagination; $i++) {
        $GetAllProductPromises[] = $this->client->getAsync($dispencery . '?page=' . $i)
            ->then(function ($response) {
                return $this->getData($response->getBody()->getContents());
            });
    }

    $data = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\all($GetAllProductPromises);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Can I used guzzle pool instead of promises If yes then what would be the major changes in my code.

Comment: You can use the pool instead, of course, but then you will have to split code to generate requests part and processing part, which is less readable IMO. That's why I always prefer to use promise control functions over the pool. If you need more concurrency control, take a look at `each_limit()` function. If you don't like functions (why?), take a look at `EachPromise` class — both the pool and `each_limit()` use this class internally, they are just thin wrappers.